# Document.domain not functioning as I'm expecting

Tags: javascript, ajax, cross-domain, access-control

I'm looking to access an API via a proxy located at bar.domain.com. And I'm accessing it via a script which is located on foo.bar.domain.com. So I ran up against the [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript), of course.

At the top of the first script loaded on foo.bar.domain.com, I set `document.domain = "bar.domain.com"`.

In the inspector, if I pause the execution immediately after this line and check document.domain, it returns bar.domain.com. Same with pausing just before the .ajax fires, and same with checking after all javascript has run.

Unfortunately, I'm still getting: `Origin http://foo.bar.domain.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.`

I wish I could give a live example, alas, I was asked not to :/

Any ideas on how I could fix or debug this? Thanks so much for any help you could give.

Comment: You are still on the same protocol? Domain.com is actually a .com domain? What browsers are you trying this with? You are not switching ports? Can you show some code?

Comment: We are indeed staying on the same protocol and ports. I'm using requireJS for my code, so here is a very simplified model of the affected pieces: http://jsfiddle.net/WSEue/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that **both** sites need to set `document.domain` to "bar.domain.com", because both pages have to explicitly indicate their willingness to interoperate.  It doesn't matter that the "bar.domain.com" page already has the same string for `document.domain` — it still must set it explicitly.

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.domain) is an MDC page with some explanation.

Comment: Digesting this at the moment. Given their note at the bottom, your thought seems correct. I'm surprised that this isn't stated more explicitly in the MDC or on other places exploring document.domain. Or maybe I've just missed it multiple times…will report back in short order.

Comment: Says the same thing [on the MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533028(v=vs.85).aspx)